# How to get a transparent status bar like the image shown below?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

[image]

I need a transparent status bar as shown in the image below.

I tried this,

```
UIView *statusBar = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] valueForKey:@"statusBarWindow"] valueForKey:@"statusBar"];

if ([statusBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundColor:)]) {
    statusBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

But this basically gives the same result as UIStatusBarStyleLightContent.

Comment: That should be how it looks by default... Can you show an image of how it looks for you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**By default, status bar has transparent background**, you just need to extend frame of your image,  behind status bar.

Here is test snapshot for you. I've set UIImageView with red background color and custom image.

[image]

Comment: _By default status bar has transparent background_  1+ for this note

Comment: Mine is set up to scaleAspectFill and is not like that.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone trying to get the imageView to go up into the "ears" of the "notch," make sure to select the imageView and its superView and set their top constraints to zero. The Interface Builder does not default the view into the notch's ears. It will have a top-layout-constraint (below the Status Bar) as default.

Comment: This just saved me from hours of finding how to put a view behind the navigation bar/status bar. Thanks.

Comment: @DustinCatap Haha, that's what Stack Overflow is for! I probably did spend hours trying to figure that out  But glad I could help!